# Performance in Kubuntu 20.04 gets progressively worse while using

Tags: kubuntu, kde, cpu, plasma

I installed Kubuntu 20.04 yesterday and I have noticed that my CPU usage is really high. It's not high when idle but even a simple mouse moving across the sceen will raise percentages on each core.

I upgraded from from Kubuntu 18.04 and noticed some performance issues so decided to upgrade.

I can't be sure if it was a similar issue but It happened after I resized my Partition to use all the space on my SSD. I had observed some issues but didn't check deeply and I was gonna upgrade anyway so wiped the drive completely

Currently 20.04 starts fine but the performance degrades the more I use it. It's at the point where I struggle to write code in VSCode because the delay is too high and the scrolling is choppy.

In Firefox the speed of starting a window is slow and opening a new tab and completing a search takes a long time.

While programming the project's development server takes too long to refresh after saving a file and reloading windows in Firefox is too slow.

It all seem to point to the high CPU usage thing, the RAM usage is fine and I didn't install anything out of the ordinary(maybe I did that doesn't work on 20.04 well).

I had noticed speed issues right after installation but they **seemed to go away after a shutdown, but it still gets slower the more I use my laptop.** It's unusable after an hour usually.

Now looking for solutions I haven't found something similar yet, any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Here's the htop otputs for two different sessions:
[image]
[image]

Comment: What do you have under `/usr/share/code`?  Whatever process is under there seems to be responsible for using the majority of your resources.   That directory doesn't exist in a default installation of Kubuntu - so it's likely something you installed.

Comment: Hi, can you please run ```sudo strace -C -p pid_of_vscode``` and interrupt it after about 10 seconds and post the output ?

Comment: There's an issue reported about  ```tsserver.js``` [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/63630) and looks like adding the option ```"typescript.disableAutomaticTypeAcquisition": true``` to the VSCode settings mitigated the problem.

Comment: does the problem happen even if you don't run VS Code?

Comment: Hey I don't believe vs code to be the sole offender here. The performnace drops will happen regardles. I looked for more solutions and turned off `blur` and `transluscency` in my desktop settings for plasma, and my system feels snappy now. To test I opened 3 different project in 3 separate vscode sessions and opened a bunch a firefox tabs. 2 tabs with 1080p videos playing. I belive turning off `blur` was the solution but I'll have to monitor performance again for a day or two make final judgements.

Comment: nice to hear. you might also want to try disabling Baloo (the file indexer) by disabling Enable File Search in System settings under Search > File search.  it's the cause of a lot of KDE performance troubles.

Comment: @ashvatthama Thanks I'll keep it in mind if I run into more performance issues, but disabling blur seems to be what fixed it, as described in the answer I added.

Comment: Hey guys, I added an update to my answer. The blur improved things a lot but the performance degradation still exists and my laptop slows down a lot after just an hour of use.

Answer (score 2):

The solution for now was to disable `Blur` in plasma System settings. I will monitor my system for more perfromance issues over a day or two but the isssue seems to be gone for now.

You'll find the Blur checkbox under `System Settings` > `WorkSpace Behaviour` > `Desktop Effects`.

I disabled `Blur` and `Translucency` but I think it's only `Blur` that you'll have to target.

It remains to be explained why this issue exists and how one can continue to use `Blur` without performnace penalties.

Edit 1 - Update after a day of use.
I turned off Baloo file indexer as well.

Good news - Performance is much better after turning off Blur.
Bad news - Performance degradation still persists and my laptop slows down significantly after just an hour of use. Blur was just one of the issues, there's something else that's causing significant performance degradation.

Comment: i tried both ubuntu and kubuntu 20.04 and i can definitely confirm that kubuntu is much much slower and buggy than ubuntu. i really like kde but it is observable with simple actions like holding and moving windows, starting apps etc. Once i experienced manjaro kde i guess 16.xx version it was flawless. You can get multiple crash notifications in Kubuntu 20.04 in every session. Like i said, i love kde but ubuntu integration is problematic. Since i need to stay with debian for business reason, my hands are tied with ubuntu gnome :)

Comment: I stuck with Kubuntu 18.04 and don't think it's bad at all, my problems turned out to be hardware based, my fan was not working correctly and thus the system would overheat and throttle.

Comment: Well im happy for you. My hw is fair enough for all distros and i change one of my fan (have two), applied new thermal paste and controlling heating all the time.